# What is the purpose of overriding from_orm classmethod in pydantic models?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I was writing models for my database tables using `pydantic`. My code does not override the `from_orm()` classmethod. However one of my peer had overridden `from_orm()` classmethod. The output looks the same for me with and without overriding. For instance,

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
    id: str
    name: Optional[str]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

**works the same as**

```
class User(BaseModel):
    id: str
    name: Optional[str]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

    @classmethod
    def from_orm(cls, obj: User):
        return User(id=obj.id, name=obj.name)
```

The [docs][1] just say

> from_orm()
> loads data into a model from an arbitrary class; cf
>
> The special constructor from_orm must be used to create the model instance

Could someone please help me understand the purpose of overriding `from_orm()` method?
[1]: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/

Comment: That sounds like a question for your coworker; there usually isn't a reason to do something like that, since it means that you have to maintain the `from_orm` override if the pydantic model changes. There might be some confusion about how `from_orm` is supposed to be used (i.e. that your coworker assumed that it had to be overridden).

Comment: May be you are right.I have nowhere seen examples of overriding `from_orm()`. I thought there must be a good reason to do so and assumed I would get some answers here.